# Criar uma animação no site do wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Estou a criar uma animação na página principal do wordpress. Para o fazer estou a fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   (function mover(i){
      
      $('#seta').animate({top: (i ? "-" : "+")+"100px"}, 1000, function(){
         mover(!i);
      });
      
   }())
   
});
```

```css
#seta{
   position: relative;
}
.container img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height:250px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.container {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="seta" class="container">

<a href="http://xxxxxxxxx.xx/recrutamento/"><img src="http://xxxxxxxxxxx.xx/wp-content/uploads/small.png" width="320" height="205" /></a>
<h1>Procura Emprego! Clique aqui!</h1>
</div>
```

Eu já testei e funciona, mas não estou a conseguir colocar a funcionar no meu site.

Mostro na imagem como estou a fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas recebo este erro na página como mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sim irá receber um erro mesmo, pelo print que mandou o Javascript está no meio de tags **`p`**.

Comment: @LeAndrade mas sem as tags, lê o código do javascript como se fosse texto, como posso resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema é simples, só não sei se vc vai conseguir resolver de forma simples.

Quando vc coloca esse script direto dentro do editor de texto do WP, o editor coloca um `<p></p>` para separar cada linha de texto *(não pode ter esse `<p>` dentro do `script`)*, pois o editor não entende o texto ali como um script, até por questão de segurança.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para tentar arrumar isso vc pode por seu script direto no Footer, ou no Header, ou mesmo na pasta dos arquivos JS do seu tema. Aqui nessa imagem da para vc ter uma ideia, sendo que esses nomes e caminho das pastas pode variar de tema para tema... O importante é vc saber que colocando o `<script>` direto dentro do editor de texto não vai dar certo. tente coloca-lo no `header.php` ou `footer.php`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No seu caso vá na guia do menu a esquerda chamada **Apresentação**, cheque as pastar e inclua o `<script>` em algum `.php` ou mesmo `.js` verificando qual seria o ideal para isso. Mas como falei vai variar de tema para tema essas pastas e nomes, mas normalmente se coloca no *footer* ou *header*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]